# File filter for open file dialog don't filter on Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

File filter for open file dialog don't filter. When i put accept: ".csv" no filtering is done and its show all files on Safari :
[link to lib Bootstrap & jQuery File Dialog](https://github.com/Saluev/bootstrap-file-dialog)

```
$.FileDialog({
        accept: ".csv",
        okButton: "OK",
        cancelButton: "Close",
        title: "Upload files",
        dropheight: 425,
    });
```

Comment: Can you try with mime type as it's written in the doc... "text/csv" instead of ".csv"

Comment: i forget for this post yes that was that, thank you, you can answer and i will check for correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the **mime type** value which is required, not the **extension**.

```
$.FileDialog({
        accept: "text/csv",     //<---- here
        okButton: "OK",
        cancelButton: "Close",
        title: "Upload files",
        dropheight: 425,
    });
```